# Android Show MediaController

Tags: android, controller, media, android-videoview

I am adding MediaController to a VideoView, but it does not show up unless I tap the phone. The controller disappears after a while.

Is there a way I can have the MediaController show always?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Default mediacontroller will hide in 3 seconds of user's inactivity. you can set the timeout seconds by

```
new media controller().show(50000);
```

check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html#show%28%29)

Comment: Note that calling show(0) will show the controller until hide() is called.

Answer (score 5):

The below code shows MediaController always:

```
VideoView videoView;   
MediaController mc;  

videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)  
    {
        public void hide()
        {
            System.out.println("HIDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEHELLLOO");
            mc.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is difference between using `setMediaController()` on a VideoView as opposed to using `setAnchorView()` on a MediaController?

Comment: Instead of mc.show(); it's this.show(); and you are not using your mc variable at all.